# extract delimited substring from field from arbitrary positions in the field using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I'm trying to extract the following substring from the following field that contains strings delimited by underscores, where the substring may not be in the same location in every cell

```
a_bsdf_cat123_adsd_esdf
a_cat345_zasd_weaq
cat123213_sdfa_sadfas_23dsafa
z_cat987_cat123_sdfaef
```

I would like the extract the first underscore delimited substring starting with the letters "cat".  So in the above example, I would like to extract

```
a_bsdf_cat123_adsd_esdf             -> cat123
a_cat345_zasd_weaq                  -> cat345
cat123213_sdfa_sadfas_23dsafa       -> cat123213
z_cat987_cat123_sdfaef              -> cat987
```

I know how to extract a substring using the substr() and instr() functions, but not when it is in different locations within the field.  How can that be done?

I need to extract this from both Oracle and MySQL.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Oracle and MySQL

Comment: Oracle: [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303). MySQL: [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr). Your profile shows you're an "Applications Engineer at Synopsys" in "Silicon Valley, CA" - I assume you can take it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

---

Try this in both:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(field, '[^|_]+cat[^_]*');
```

Comment: This will find `cat123` in `acat123_cat456` when it should find `cat456`.